# Concatenating a String from Array in Android before API 26

Tags: android

I was concatenating a `String` from an `Array` with the following code:

```
protected void buildString(String[] strings) {

Arrays.sort(strings);

String s = String.join("", strings);

return s;

}
```

On this line: `String s = String.join("", strings);`, Android Studio displayed an error that could be corrected by wrapping it in a conditional:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
String s = String.join("", strings);
}
```

What is the `else` supposed to be on older versions of Android? I don't want any concatenation, I just want a joined string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough, should just use `TextUtils` instead:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String s = String.join("", strings);
    } else {
        String s = TextUtils.join("", strings);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use TextUtils regardless of OS?

Comment: Yes. TextUtils are much better here.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use Stream(Java 8 and above) simply like this.

```
Stream.of(strings).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```